# how to fix download works on browser but on wget doesn't work?

Tags: wget

so I wanted to download a video when I get the link and paste it into the browser it pops up a download notice and start downloading and when I try the same link on wget it dosn't work.

Keep in mind i'm not logged in when downloading the link
I tried to downloading it from incognito mode and from different browsers and it works fine
but in wget it output the following message:

```
Connecting to [websiteLINK] connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized.

Username/Password Authentication Failed
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, any ideas?

Comment: Looks like the site requires logging in. Do you log in when accessing the site from browser? If yes, you need to provide the same login & password as parameters to `wget`.

Comment: no, I don't login to the site in any way

Comment: Hello. The site might simply not allow that kind of download.

Comment: Isn't there any work around it?

Comment: Contact the site owners and ask them. Nothing here that has anything to do with the Ubuntu OS.

Comment: You write that the site "pops up a download notice". This may be the clue. What is exactly that notice? Do you mean a standard dialog displayed by the browser or some pop-up displayed by the site itself, which contains some button that you need to click to download the file? The button may trigger some Javascript that authenticates to the site in some way. You need to analyze the code and mimic the behaviour of that button and use possible authorization data that it sends to the site.

Comment: the popup that I was referring to is by the chrome and the firefox browsers, by default downloads go to the download folder but i changed the settings to "ask every time for download location", the site isn't displaying any popups, and the button that i click isn't giving any popup only the direct link to the media in my case is [site-domain].mp4.

Comment: can please past the link here, i want to try in my machine...